# How to get data from existing MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database on [mlab](https://mlab.com/) and now I was starting a new Project and trying to simply get data from there.

The Database has only one collection called **Article**.

On my **Node js** project, using **Mongoose**, I created the Model for it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: String }
});

var Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

module.exports = Article;
```

The in my controller I just did this:

```
Article.find({}, function (err, articles) {
    res.send(articles);
});
```

I should receive more than 300 articles but the response is just an empty Array.

I was wondering if I need to run a few more command in order to connect to the db correctly, but I don't know it...

Comment: you have `var Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);`, but you define `article`, not `articleSchema`, one line above. Can this be the issue?

Comment: @TudorConstantin thanks for your hint, I just checked and I misstyped here in Stackoverflow... I just edited the question.

Comment: Do you get any errors while connecting (code not presented)? Maybe you are connecting to a different uri and therefore the articles collection is empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to fetch on an existing **Article** collection:

```
var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: String }
}, { collection : 'Article' });
```

Comment: This is just a more complicated version of the very same code. I don't know how this answers any problem?

Comment: No I think `{ collection : 'Article' }` solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, it was enough to write to add `{ collection : 'Article' }` to answer my question, it should be better to edit the answer to better fit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Good catch Thomi! You just should've answered it straightly that there's a typo/difference in the collection name, rather than writing code for separate files. Anyways, good work!